# Accord and Mulit-label Support Vector Machines

Tags: c#, accord.net

I'm working through the example in the docs for a multi-class support vector machine - http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_VectorMachines_MultilabelSupportVectorMachine.htm

Though, I'm not getting a 0 error rate, and when I try to compute values, they do not give the output values they should. Is there something wrong with the example?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Sample input data
        double[][] inputs =
        {
            new double[] { 0 },
            new double[] { 1 },
            new double[] { 2 },
            new double[] { 3 },
        };

        // Outputs for each of the inputs
        int[][] outputs =
            {
                new[] {1,-1,-1,-1}, 
                new[] {-1,1,-1,-1}, 
                new[] {-1,-1,1,-1}, 
                new[] {-1,-1,-1,1}, 
            };

        // Create a new Linear kernel
        IKernel kernel = new Linear();

        // Create a new Multi-class Support Vector Machine with one input,
        //  using the linear kernel and for four disjoint classes.
        var machine = new MultilabelSupportVectorMachine(1, kernel, 4);

        // Create the Multi-label learning algorithm for the machine
        var teacher = new MultilabelSupportVectorLearning(machine, inputs, outputs);

        // Configure the learning algorithm to use SMO to train the
        //  underlying SVMs in each of the binary class subproblems.
        teacher.Algorithm = (svm, classInputs, classOutputs, i, j) =>
            new SequentialMinimalOptimization(svm, classInputs, classOutputs);

        // Run the learning algorithm
        double error = teacher.Run();

        error = teacher.Run(); // 0.1875 error rate
        var answer = machine.Compute(new double[] {2});  // gives -1,-1,-1,-1, instead of -1,-1,1,-1
```

Should the error rate be zero, and why does it seem that only an input of `0` gives the right output?

Comment: So, why the close vote? Is it my stalker who has a point to prove?

Comment: the people who has no knowledge and doesn't know the answer will always vote for close. you will learn it too :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, it is very likely that there was something wrong with that particular example. Most examples have been updated to reflect the new .Learn() API that was put in place last year.

Now you may see that the documentation page for Multi-label Support Vector Machine has also changed addresses due the new API and is now at

- http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_VectorMachines_MultilabelSupportVectorMachine_1.htm

And now it includes this example, among others:

```
// Let's say we have the following data to be classified
// into three possible classes. Those are the samples:
// 
double[][] inputs =
{
    //               input         output
    new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, //  0 
    new double[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //  0
    new double[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, //  0
    new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, //  0
    new double[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //  0
    new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //  1
    new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //  1
    new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
    new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
    new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
    new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
    new double[] { 1, 0, 1, 1 }, //  2
    new double[] { 1, 1, 0, 1 }, //  2
    new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
    new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
};

int[] outputs = // those are the class labels
{
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
};

// Create the multi-class learning algorithm for the machine
var teacher = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<Gaussian>()
{
    // Configure the learning algorithm to use SMO to train the
    //  underlying SVMs in each of the binary class subproblems.
    Learner = (param) => new SequentialMinimalOptimization<Gaussian>()
    {
        // Estimate a suitable guess for the Gaussian kernel's parameters.
        // This estimate can serve as a starting point for a grid search.
        UseKernelEstimation = true
    }
};

// Configure parallel execution options
teacher.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;

// Learn a machine
var machine = teacher.Learn(inputs, outputs);

// Obtain class predictions for each sample
int[] predicted = machine.Decide(inputs);

// Get class scores for each sample
double[] scores = machine.Score(inputs);

// Compute classification error
double error = new ZeroOneLoss(outputs).Loss(predicted);
```